# Sonar fails on analysis Unable to create symbol table for

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

when i run analysis with SonarQube 5.0.1 i receive the following exception
on java source

I'm running this analysis with maven project by running the following command :
mvn sonar:sonar -Psonar
Please help Gidi

```
[22:04:35]: [ERROR] [22:04:35.535] Class not found: javafx.beans.Observable
[22:04:35]: [ERROR] [22:04:35.884] Class not found: javafx.beans.Observable
[22:04:36]: [ERROR] [22:04:36.403] Class not found: javafx.beans.Observable
[22:04:37]: [ERROR] [22:04:37.014] Unable to create symbol table for : /home/ciuser/buildAgent/work/f9bff052f3e7989d/cobrowse-server/cobrowse-server-core/src/main/java/net/synchronite/common/ImmutableCollectors.java
[22:04:37]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type not resolved methodReference tokenValue='ImmutableMap' tokenLine=31 tokenColumn=62
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.resolveAs(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:275) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.resolveAs(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:241) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.resolveAs(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:234) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitVariable(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:453) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.VariableTreeImpl.accept(VariableTreeImpl.java:180) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:36) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitBlock(BaseTreeVisitor.java:85) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.model.statement.BlockTreeImpl.accept(BlockTreeImpl.java:91) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitMethod(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:108) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.MethodTreeImpl.accept(MethodTreeImpl.java:201) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:36) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.resolve.TypeAndReferenceSolver.visitClass(TypeAndReferenceSolver.java:117) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.model.declaration.ClassTreeImpl.accept(ClassTreeImpl.java:201) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:42) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.scan(BaseTreeVisitor.java:36) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.api.tree.BaseTreeVisitor.visitCompilationUnit(BaseTreeVisitor.java:55) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.resolve.SemanticModel.createFor(SemanticModel.java:66) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:111) ~[java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at com.sonar.sslr.impl.ast.AstWalker.walkAndVisit(AstWalker.java:67) [sslr-core-1.20.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.simpleScan(AstScanner.java:107) [java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.ast.AstScanner.scan(AstScanner.java:75) [java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:122) [java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:115) [java-squid-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:91) [sonar-java-plugin-2.8.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:122) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67) [sonar-batch-maven-compat-5.0.1.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48) [sonar-runner-batch7101932206275395209.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100) [sonar-runner-api-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:135) [sonar-maven-plugin-2.5.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:138) [sonar-maven-plugin-2.5.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156) [maven-core-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141) [maven-embedder-3.0.4.jar:3.0.4]
[22:04:37]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
[22:04:37]:     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
[22:04:37]:     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352) [plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:na]
```

Comment: Would it be possible to share the code of the `ImmutableCollectors` class ? That would allow to help you.

Comment: I suspect this is linked to this issue : http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-876 So would you be able to share the line 31 of your file ? Thanks

Comment: final Supplier<ImmutableMap.Builder<K, V>> supplier = ImmutableMap.Builder::new;

Comment: For sake of clarity, please edit your post with this line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are encoutering the following issue : 
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARJAVA-876

Basically, the type of the method reference expression is not resolved nor set. You are thus encountering this illegal state exception as an expression should always have a type.

As seen from your logs, you are using sonar-java plugin version 2.8, please update your plugin to the latest version to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse right click the project-->properties-->Java Build Path-->Libraries tab-->JRE System library and click edit button.

Click alternate JRE-->Installed JRE--->Search

Navigate to Java installed folder and select
[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281]

click apply and run your project

Comment: This solved my issue as I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced a similar issue. The is because of the java version incompatibility as @Ahmed Ashour said in the previous answer. In SonarQube we portal, update SonarJava plugin under Administration => Marketplace => search for SonarJava and update it to latest version. Then restart the SonarQube.

[Screenshot for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nec1h.png)